# UIImage leak in Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios6, instruments

When UIButton is pressed to load images from file for scrollview it leaks in instruments

**Leaked Object** is UIImage

**Size** is 48 Bytes

**Responsible Library** is Foundation

**Responsible Frame** is _NSThread_main_

when i click on the address arrow to get history

**Category  Event Type  RefCt   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller**

Malloc 32 Bytes Malloc            1 32  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
Malloc 32 Bytes Free              0 -32 libsystem_c.dylib   asl_client_release
UIImage         Malloc            1      48 Foundation          **NSThread_*main***
UIImage         Retain            2 0   Foundation          **NSThread_main**
UIImage         Retain            3 0   Foundation  __NSThreadPerformPerform
UIImage         Retain            4 0   Foundation  __NSThreadPerformPerform
UIImage         Release           3 0   Foundation  __NSThreadPerformPerform
UIImage         Retain            4 0   Foundation  -[NSInvocationOperation main]
UIImage         Retain            5 0   Foundation  -[NSInvocationOperation main]
UIImage         Release           4 0   Foundation  -[NSInvocationOperation main]
UIImage         Release           3 0   Foundation  -[NSInvocationOperation main]
UIImage         Release           2 0   Foundation  __NSThreadPerformPerform
UIImage         Release           1 0   Foundation  -[NSInvocationOperation dealloc]

```
-(void)ScrollView:(id)sender
{
NSMutableArray *photos = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];

Photo *photo;

photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image0" ofType:@"png"]];
[photos addObject:photo];

photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"png"]];
[photos addObject:photo];

photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image2" ofType:@"png"]];
[photos addObject:photo];

photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image3" ofType:@"png"]];
[photos addObject:photo];

photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image4" ofType:@"png"]];
[photos addObject:photo];

photo = [Photo photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image5" ofType:@"png"]];
[photos addObject:photo];

 ImageViewController *imageviewcontroller = [[[ImageViewController alloc] initWithPhotos:photos]autorelease];

imageviewcontroller.displayActionButton = YES;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:imageviewcontroller]autorelease];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

 + (Photo *)photoWithFilePath:(NSString *)path {
return [[[Photo alloc] initWithFilePath:path]autorelease];
```

If someone could give some ideas on what the issue could be, then that would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to find the problem if we can see some code, not just the callstack.

Comment: i updated my question with code

Comment: Could you also drop in Photo object with photoWithFilePath: ?

Comment: 48 bytes? not sure what is leaking (if anything), but at 48 bytes it isn't likely to be a UIImage. What does that initWithFilePath method looks like for your Photo class?

Comment: may be ur autorelease is causing this problem.. remove all the autorelease statements and have release statements at proper place, and also u r adding the photo objects in the photos list with the same pointer.. make these changes & check once again.